# Login Loop on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, login, lightdm, desktop-environments, gdm

I am a beginner Linux user and have been using, as mentioned, **Ubuntu 18.04.1** for about three months. So far, since I know I lack sufficient experience, I have avoided messing with anything tricky or dangerous-looking in the command-line.

Then, a couple days ago, I ran into a problem.  After rebooting my computer, and typing in my password as usual, the screen went black for a few seconds, and then showed up at the login manager again. And again.  And again.  **The Login Loop**.  I've heard of it before.

So obviously, what caused it, and how do I fix it?

That's what I need help with.

I was aware that this question has been asked before, so I looked around to see if I could find some things out.  First, I found out that my login manager was **GDM3**, and there could be problems with that.
So I tried installing **LightDM** and using that instead. No luck.

Next, I tried using the **Cinnamon** desktop environment that I had installed several weeks ago.  That didn't work either.  Something came up about Cinnamon needing to be restarted, which it never successfully did.

Note: *I did not have Cinnamon running when I ran into this problem, I only tested it briefly a while ago.  My current desktop environment is the default that was there when I first installed Ubuntu.  I assume that is called 'Ubuntu' or 'Gnome', but I don't really know.*

Then I read something about the **Xauthority** file possibly causing an issue.  I used `cat .xsession-errors` to check that and it showed my username as still owning it.  So apparently no problem there.

---

***Update.  This is the content I get from running `cat .xsession-errors`:

```
`dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/kaleb/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_US
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/LXDE.mandatory.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/kaleb
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=kaleb
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=LXDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/LXDE.default.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/kaleb
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/kaleb
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/LXDE:/home/kaleb/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=LXDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_US
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=LXDE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=kaleb
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/kaleb/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-LXDE:/etc/xdg
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
** Message: 10:18:58.669: main.vala:102: Session is LXDE
** Message: 10:18:58.669: main.vala:103: DE is LXDE

(lxsession:4531): dbind-WARNING **: 10:18:58.718: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-UrEFunK9WL: Connection refused
** Message: 10:18:58.729: main.vala:134: log directory: /home/kaleb/.cache/lxsession/LXDE
** Message: 10:18:58.729: main.vala:135: log path: /home/kaleb/.cache/lxsession/LXDE/run.log`
```

Does this help at all?
Let me know if I can post any more useful information.

---

Later, I was able to install the Lubuntu desktop environment and successfully log in to my account.  That's a far cry from my original position though, and the problem still isn't fixed.

I really have no idea how the problem started though.
The only unusual things I can think I did before the problem started were:

1. Installed *Alacarte* from software manager to edit application icon.
2. Used `sudo nautilus` in the terminal to get into some files that were locked.  This was in regards to the application icon I was trying to change; nothing system-related.

I did nothing else out of the ordinary before the reboot.

Any help on how to diagnose and fix this Login Loop would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just fyi:  GUI logins require the creation & use of temporary work files which are created in your $HOME (user directory).  If you have insufficient space in your user directory ($HOME) the creation of those files fails and you are logged out (ie. login loop without message).  You can still login via terminal, check you have space in $HOME, or `rm` files if necessary, then switch to GUI and re-login normally.

Comment: @guiverc  Thanks for the tip.  Last I checked, my Home drive was only %50 full, unless I'm missing something.  I did figure out how to log in via the terminal.
Is there a specific command I can enter to see how much space is left in my Home folder?

Comment: I use `df -hl`  (disk free, human & local-only options... -- i use 'human' so I don't get huge numbers, 'local' so I don't get a list of NFS storage drives too which you may not have)

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chown -R $USER ~/*`  (chown = change ownership, -R so it's recursive, $USER will be/become your username, ~ is shorthand for your user directory).  By using `sudo nautilus` you may have edited/changed a file and made the owner 'root' & denied your user access to whatever you changed (its no longer owned by you, but became a 'root' owned file) whilst the elevated privileges within `nautilus`

Comment: @guiverc  No, I don't believe I've tried that yet.  I did check my `Xauthority` file somehow, to make sure it was still owned by me, which it was, but I'm not sure if you're talking about that file or not.  Should I enter the code '`sudo chown -R $USER ~/*`' exactly as it is shown in your comment?

Comment: Yeah it may not help, but it may.  The $USER will be expanded to your user name (as I don't know it) and you can just put ~ (which will be the same as ~/\* ; I think I typed it as \* then decided you should have directory so added the ~/ to it).  It will just ensure any file located in or under your $HOME directory will be owned by you (which should be the case; ie. undo anything you've done by using elevated privileges or `sudo` that may have changed ownership away from you).

Comment: @guiverc Entering `sudo chown -R $kaleb ~/` (my username is just 'kaleb') gives me the error `chown: missing operand after '/'`.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you enter `echo $USER` you'll see your username (which I assume now is kaleb) be printed.  If you want to use your username, it's `sudo chown -R kaleb ~`  (the $USER is a variable which will be substituted with the username I didn't know, ie. `echo $USER` prints "guiverc" for me as that's my username. The $ tells bash/shell to use the variable of the name after the $  (ie. $USER will contain your username, $PWD will be your present.working.directory etc).  Because I didn't know your username, $USER would become it (or you can substitute it yourself too as you did if you remove the $)

Comment: @guiverc  Alright, entering `sudo chown -R kaleb ~` exactly into the terminal made a ton of black-and-white stuff go scrolling by for a few minutes, saying it was changing ownership on everything.  Then everything became dis-functional, and after reboot I have a black screen with a blinking white cursor.  I think I should reinstall now.  Like I asked earlier, should I choose the 'reinstall' or 'something else' option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been solved already but I had a similar issue where after updating I was stuck in the login loop. This solution is only for those that have a NVIDIA driver already installed. During the update process some how nouveau was enabled. Solution:

1)  create file blacklist-nouveau.conf in /etc/modprob.d

2) Add below contents:
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

3) Regenerate the kernel initramfs with below command:
sudo update initramfs -u

4) reboot

I tried so many solutions online and none of them worked. Hope this helps someone.