# How to completely uninstall and reinstall a desktop environment?

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, desktop-environments

Recently, I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121867/login-loop-on-ubuntu-18-04-1) on how to solve a login loop on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

My problem seems to be specifically associated with the Ubuntu desktop environment, as I am able to successfully login using the LXDE environment.  And so I thought if I could completely uninstall and then reinstall that desktop environment, I might be able to login again.

The problem is, I don't know what exactly my desktop-environment is called, or how to completely remove it.  It is the default I have used ever since first installing Ubuntu, but, being a very inexperienced Linux user, I don't know what it's actually called.

Could anyone suggest a way to find out what my desktop-environment is, and how to uninstall/reinstall it?

Comment: `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` should display your current environment.  For me it responds "Lubuntu" (which makes sense, I'm logged in and using LXQt).  The default GUI/Desktop environment installed with Ubuntu 18.04 (or any release) is found in package `ubuntu-desktop`  (*Lubuntu with `lubuntu-desktop`, Xubuntu uses `xubuntu-desktop` etc*)

Comment: If you are switching the Desktop Environment from login screen, there must be a list of installed DE. You can determine your default DE from there and reinstall it from another DE or TTY mode using `sudo apt install --reinstall <package name>` and reboot the system.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc and @Kulfy for your help.  I was able to uninstall/reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` environment with the command  `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, however, it didn't quite solve my problem. 
What I am wanting is this:  how do you completely _remove_ a desktop environment so I can reinstall it later?
Giving the previous command only removed about 10 KBs of data -- the desktop environment still seems to be there.  Is there a command to entirely delete it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Most desktops have common components, eg. GNOME uses the GTK+ software stack, as does Unity, MATE, XFCE, LXDE & more.  KDE & LXQt & others however used the Qt stack so it's not all.  If you had two installed (LXDE (gtk+2) & GNOME (gtk+3)), removing one will naturally leave some components behind as they are used by your other environment, and I'm wondering if this is what you mean.  Another thought is `apt remove` removes the package but leaves the conf files allowing re-install, you could `apt purge` to remove more, but would need to start again if you re-install